# How to use visual studio development server in VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

How to test WCF service/Website with the help of "Visual Studio Development Server" instead of local IIS in Visual Studio 2015? Following image is of property page of WCF service project which dont have option to use Visual Studio Development Server. I am using Enterprise edition of VS2015. [image]

Comment: What's wrong with using IIS Express?

Comment: @Ric It does required admin credentials to do so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "Visual Studio Development Server" is no longer available in Visual Studio 2015, it has been replaced by IIS Express (as you see in your screenshot).  This **is not** the same as installing the version of IIS that comes with Windows.  But functions almost identically, so your development/testing environment is much closer to what it would [likely] look like in production.

Comment: I only have blurred memories, but IIS always seemed to require some configuration to work, while VS Dev Server never had a problem, just 'F5 and Play'. Rest in peace.